# How to save workspace when running multiple lines of R scripts with batch file

Tags: r, batch-file

I am trying to run multiple R statements in a batch file to read an csv and train a model as below

```
"D:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64\Rscript" -e "library(C50)" --save
"D:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64\Rscript" -e "load('E:/ALGO/batch/.Rdata')"
"D:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64\Rscript" -e "C50Training<-read.csv(file='E:/algo/dataset/C50Training.csv',header=TRUE)" --save
"D:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64\Rscript" -e "load('E:/ALGO/batch/.Rdata')"
"D:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64\Rscript" -e  "capture.output(summary(C50Training), file = 'E:/ALGO/summary/C50TrainingSum.txt')" --save
"D:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64\Rscript" -e "load('E:/ALGO/batch/.Rdata')"
"D:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64\Rscript" -e "C50fit<-C5.0(formula=AAA~AAB+AAC+AAD+AAE+AAF,data=C50Training)" --save
"D:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64\Rscript" -e "load('E:/ALGO/batch/.Rdata')"
"D:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64\Rscript" -e "capture.output(summary(C50fit),file='E:/ALGO/summary/SummC50fit.txt')" --save
```

but it did not work becuase by going through each batch line R does not save its work space even though I added `--save` and load `.Rdata` for each line. It did work when I included all R statements into one batch line, seperated by semi-colon as below.

```
"D:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64\Rscript" -e "library(C50);C50Training<-read.csv(file='E:/algo/dataset/C50Training.csv',header=TRUE);C50fit<-C5.0(formula=AAA~AAB+AAC+AAD+AAE+AAF,data=C50Training);capture.output(summary(C50fit),file='E:/ALGO/summary/SummC50fit.txt');"
```

Is there a way I can run each R statement with one single batch line?

Many thanks

Comment: you should create a single R file and call it in Batch file and save the workspace in the R file itself

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is to create e single R files that contains everything you want to run and the call it with the command:

```
source("path/to/your/file.R")
```

In this way the file you have created will be called and executed

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The thing is I want to work everything out in VBA environment. So not knowing how to create a R file with VBA, I can only write R commands into a batch file before running it. Feel free to let me know it is possible to create a R file in VBA.